# Why we need OIDC ID Token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, access-token

I'm researching to use OIDC for SSO (Single Sign On).

I know OIDC flow always return `id_token` and `access_token` but I don't know why we need `id_token`?

As I know `id_token` used only by client application to get authenticated user information. Client application will decode and verify JWT then extract user information from it.

But because I have `access_token`, I can use it to get user information from endpoint `/userinfo`. So I dont't need `id_token`?

Please help me understand the right way to use `id_token`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can get the user details using the access token from the /userinfo endpoint.

The ID-token represents details about the user and more important **how** the user authenticated (password, 2FA...). The lifetime of the Id-token is often very short (like a few minutes).

Just like how the [specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) describes it:

*The ID Token is a security token that contains Claims about the Authentication of an End-User by an Authorization Server when using a Client, and potentially other requested Claims.*